# Print says the whole variable

Tags: python, printing

So I've been trying to make it so I can print out a long line so I can be able to have it look fancy but doesn't seem to be working like normal...

```
playerguess = input()
playerguess = int(playerguess)
days = 2
example = ("Looks like this storm won't stop for another ", days + playerguess, " we will have to wait")
print("-Captain Strand- \"", example, "\" (You can barely hear him but thats all you hear)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example, you probably meant to use `"".join(example)`, however, you may really want to template a multiline string and use [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) (which are both methods of the *string*)

```
TEMPLATE = """{header}
"Looks like this storm won't stop for another {days}, we will have to wait"
(You can barely hear him but thats all you hear)"""

TEMPLATE.format(
    header="-Captain Strand-",
    days=days + playerguess,
)
```

```py
>>> print(TEMPLATE.format(
...     header="-Captain Strand-",
...     days=days + playerguess,
... ))
-Captain Strand-
"Looks like this storm won't stop for another 5, we will have to wait"
(You can barely hear him but thats all you hear)
```

originally

```py
>>> example = ("Looks like this storm won't stop for another ", days + playerguess, " we will have to wait")
>>> example  # example is a tuple of strings
("Looks like this storm won't stop for another ", 5, ' we will have to wait')
>>> example = "".join(("Looks like this storm won't stop for another ", str(days + playerguess), " we will have to wait"))
>>> example  # example is a single string
"Looks like this storm won't stop for another 5 we will have to wait"
```

Comment: anytime! I also added the double-quotes back in to show that they can be embedded in the multiline string